# I need to access a library command in a different method in my code

Tags: java, android

Okay so I'm going to try to make this as simple as possible as I just keep getting confused thinking about it. So I'm using a library called AchievementUnlocked which you can find here [Github Link](https://github.com/DarkionAvey/AchievementUnlocked-library)

So yeah I'll post the code below but basically I need to access the method below from another method in my activity.

Method I need to access:

```
public void notification() {
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(duration);
    notificationstatus = "ACTIVE";


    final AchievementUnlocked achievementUnlocked = new AchievementUnlocked(MainActivity.this).setTitle(title).
            setSubtitleColor(Color.parseColor(colortxt)).
            setSubTitle(text).
            setDuration(Settings.Time).
            setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorbg)).
            setTitleColor(Color.parseColor(colortxt)).
            setIcon(getDrawableFromRes(image1)).
            isLarge(Settings.largepref).build();

    View iconIV = achievementUnlocked.getIconView();
    ObjectAnimator outX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iconIV, "scaleX", 0.9f, 0.7f);
    ObjectAnimator outY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iconIV, "scaleY", 0.9f, 0.7f);
    ObjectAnimator inX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iconIV, "scaleX", 0.7f, 0.9f);
    ObjectAnimator inY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iconIV, "scaleY", 0.7f, 0.9f);
    final AnimatorSet Outset = new AnimatorSet();
    final AnimatorSet Ani = new AnimatorSet();
    final AnimatorSet Inset = new AnimatorSet();
    outX.setDuration(1000);
    outY.setDuration(1000);
    inX.setDuration(1000);
    inY.setDuration(1000);
    Ani.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            Ani.start();
        }
    });
    Outset.playTogether(outX, outY);
    Inset.playTogether(inX, inY);
    (achievementUnlocked.getAchievementView()).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            achievementUnlocked.dismiss();
            NotificationService.run();
        }
    });
    achievementUnlocked.getAchievementView().setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);


    Ani.play(Outset).before(Inset);
    achievementUnlocked.setAchievementListener(new AchievementUnlocked.achievementListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAchievementBeingCreated(AchievementUnlocked achievement, boolean created) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAchievementExpanding(AchievementUnlocked achievement, boolean expanded) {
            if (expanded) Ani.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAchievementShrinking(AchievementUnlocked achievement, boolean shrunken) {
            if (!shrunken) {
                if (Ani.isRunning())
                    Ani.cancel();
                notificationstatus = "UNACTIVE";
                Log.i("Status Set UNACTIVE", notificationstatus);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onAchievementBeingDestroyed(AchievementUnlocked achievement, boolean destroyed) {

        }
    });

    achievementUnlocked.show();

}
```

I need to access that method from this section of code:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener    {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // left to right swipe
            if(e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                **Rightswipe();**
            }
            // right to left swipe
            else if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                **Leftswipe();**
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

So my main question is how can I act like I'm inside the original method from my second method because the function `achievementUnlocked.dismiss();` is not accessible outside of the main method you see first . I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Add a setter to `MyGestureDetector` that takes an `AchievementUnlocked` as a parameter. Store that `AchievementUnlocked` in a field in `MyGestureDetector`. Call that setter from `notification()`. Then, `MyGestureDetector` has access to the `AchievementUnlocked` instance and can call `dismiss()` on it.

Comment: So is there anyway you can post example code for this as this all sounds super foreign to me? Im really new to Android coding and learning day by day new things that are super useful like this thanks to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: @SkylerMartin: Um, fields, setters, and such are *very* rudimentary Java. See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) for a discussion of fields, getters, and setters. In the `Bicycle` example class there, `cadence` is an example of a field, `getCadence()` is an example of a getter method, and `setCadence()` is an example of a setter method.

Comment: I understand its a super basic concept but I mean if you know what your doing and you could fit it to my code I would be happy to pay you!